# how to identify the process for a batch file run through a vbscript

Tags: windows, batch

I used this forum to figure out how to run tomcat batch file silently/hidden using vbscript. The code I used is this:

```vbs
Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") 
Dim strArgs
strArgs = "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\catalina.bat run"
oShell.Run strArgs, 0, false
```

However, I cannot figure out how to stop this process since I cannot identify it in the task manager. How can I identify a process ran in this manner?

Comment: any luck lookin in the "command line" column in task manager? try options..select columns, if it's not there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a slightly modified script (as I don't *know* whether `%CATALINA_HOME%` contains a space):

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Dim strArgs
strArgs = """%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\catalina.bat"" run"
oShell.Run strArgs, 0, false
```

use (from command line interpreter window)

```
wmic process where "name='cmd.exe'" get CommandLine, ProcessId
```

and then narrow the output as follows:

```
wmic process where "name='cmd.exe'" get CommandLine, ProcessId|findstr "catalina"
```

`Wmic` output could be parsed with `for /F` command. See Dave Benham's *[`WMIC` and `FOR /F`: A fix for the trailing `<CR>` problem](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4266)*.

**Edit**. In next code snippet, there is merely `echo taskkill` instead of operational `taskkill`; also note `%` is doubled in [WQL (SQL for WMI)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394606(v=vs.85).aspx) query as `%%` (escaped it's special meaning in Windows CLI):

```
for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%G in (
      `wmic process where "CommandLine like '%%catalina.bat%%' AND Caption like '%%cmd.exe%%'" get ProcessID/value ^|find /I "="`
    ) do (
        for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%H in ("%%~G") do echo taskkill /T /F /PID %%H  
    )
```

Comment: Thanks Josef. ok, so that worked for me. I get the output as - C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c ""C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\bin\catalina.bat" run"  4516 . I need to extract the PID from this string. I have tried using FOR /F to extract the PID from this output but haven't been able to get it to work. Any pointers pls ?